# How do I select rows within a dataframe which start with the same phrase, without having to individually select the rows, within python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

How do I create a column in my dataframe called 'Declined Or Hired', where a '1' is input into each row where the (Declined - Reason) Or Hire column starts with "Offer Declined -...). My code below works, however I think I've written a long solution, which could be shorter.

`df.loc[(df['(Declined - Reason) Or Hire'] == 'Offer Declined - Accepted Another Offer') | (df['(Declined - Reason) Or Hire'] == 'Offer Declined - Company'), 'Declined Or Hired'] ='1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and convert the booleans to integers with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Declined or Hired'] = (df['(Declined - Reason) Or Hire']
                          .str.startswith('Offer Declined', na=False)
                          .astype(int)
                          )
```

If you want to match anywhere (not only on start), rather use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: I get this error message, when I try your code - "cannot convert float NaN to integer" Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Likely because you initially have NaNs, check the update

Comment: @monzway This works, thank you! One last question. Could I add an "and" operator to your code, if I wanted the equation to also be based on another column like df['Job ID'] == '9375ba57-19ba-43a1-86c2-c76c97b6dd4a'? And if so, where would I add this part to your formula?

Comment: If I understand correctly: `(df[…].str.startswith(…) & df['Job ID'].eq(…)).astype(int)`. If not, please open a new question ;)